# Typo in Lang's Algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

On p. 643 of Lang's *Algebra*, revised 3rd edition, he writes

> **Remark:** Let $E$ be a 1-dimensional vector space over a division ring $D$, and let $\{v\}$ be a basis. For each $a \in D$, there exists
>   a unique $D$ linear map $f_a: E \to E$ such that $f_a(v) = av.$ Then
>   we have the rule $$f_af_b=f_{ba}.$$

I just cannot understand what he means. It would make sense to me if he said $f_a(v) = va$ (this would then be a left module homomorphism). I doubt it is a typo, since it's been through three editions and this would be a pretty glaring one...also I did not find it in the errata.

What am I missing?

Comment: The only thing I wonder about is the interpretation of "$fg$". This juxtaposition might mean "$f\circ g$" but it looks like it probably means "first apply $f$, then apply $g$", i.e., "$g\circ f$". In that case, it works, right?

Comment: The problem is that $f_a$ is not left linear if $D$ is not commutative.

Comment: @MPW If he means that $E$ is a right module, then yes...but that is two strange things piled on top of each other.

Comment: It does appear to me that the notation is not consistent: I agree with MPW that the order in which you compose the functions is the key issue.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson But then wouldn't $E$ have to be a right module? Strange he wouldn't mention that

Comment: Lang was a wonderful mathematician and usually a great expositor; but his books are notorious for their errors.

Comment: I find it confusing in that $f_{a}(v) = av$ suggests a left action of $D$ on $E$, yet as MPW says, you need to compose functions from right to left.

Comment: Good that *my* Lang ands on page 499 already ;)

Comment: Read $f_af_b=f_b\circ f_a$ is not that unusual. $f_a$ is applied first, so it is first in the order. This is common for permutations, in particular.

Comment: @EricAuld: Note that this has nothing to do with left or right modules. This is just a convention for writing down the name of a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out with the help of a bright math professor.The issue is not the way that function composition is written, nor is there a typo.

The function $f_a$ is *not* defined by "left multiply the argument by $a$". Rather, it is defined by the fact that it maps the generator $v \mapsto av$, and from there we extend left-linearly. The same is true of $f_b$; therefore, $f_a(bv):= b f_a(v)= bav$.

Why go to all this trouble instead of just defining a left module homomorphism by $v \mapsto va$? Because, for a general left module $E$ over $D$, there is no right multiplication by a scalar. The special case $E=D$ does have a right multiplication defined, though, and we do know that $E \cong D$ as left $D$ modules, so we can work with that.

This is all by way of showing that $D^{op} \cong \text{End}_D(E)$ as rings, when $E$ is one-dimensional. I believe they cannot be made into $D$ algebras since $a \phi$ is not necessarily in $\text{End}_D(E)$ if $\phi$ is.